# Extract fields from json using jq

Tags: jq

I am trying write a shell script that will get some json from URL and parse the json and extract fields.
This is what is done so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

token=$(http POST :3000/signin/frontm user:='{"email": "sourav@frontm.com", "password": "Hello_789"}' | jq -r '.data.id_token')   
cred=$(http POST :3000/auth provider_name:frontm token:$token user:=@/tmp/user.json | jq '{ creds: .creds, userUuid: .user.userId }')

echo $cred
access=$(jq -r "'$cred'")
echo $access
```

So the output from echo $cred is a json:
Eg:

```
{ "creds": { "accessKeyId": "ASIAJPM3RDAZXEORAQ5Q", "secretAccessK
ey": "krg5GbU6gtQV+a5pz4ChL+ECVJm+wKogjglXOqr6", "sessionToken": "Ag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" }, "userUuid": "mugqRKHmTPxk
obBAtwTmKk" }
```

So basically I am stuck here .. how do i parse this json in $cred further and basically want to get access to say accessKeyId using jq further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if the variable `$cred` really holds a string formated in 67 columns, but if that so, `tr` might help to remove the newline and extract the `accessKeyId` using `jq`:

```
echo "$cred" | tr -d '\n'  | jq -r '.creds.accessKeyId'
```

Comment: I could figure it out basically echo "$cred" did the trick for me to pipe it to jq and the its just extracting the field.. Thanks